# WorkManager google api: wait 15 minutes for every periodic worker execution?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Is there a way to test a **PERIODIC** worker from WorkManager Google API without waiting at least 15 minutes for every execution?

I mean, it is a DEBUG app and I'm running it through Android Studio and I don't want to wait such a long time to test my features.

Answer (score 3):

You **can't**.

Periodic work has a minimum interval of 15 minutes and it cannot have an initial delay. You can find the proof in the `WorkSpec.java` class.

```java
 /**
     * Sets the periodic interval for this unit of work.
     *
     * @param intervalDuration The interval in milliseconds
     */
    public void setPeriodic(long intervalDuration) {
        if (intervalDuration < MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS) {
            Logger.get().warning(TAG, String.format(
                    "Interval duration lesser than minimum allowed value; Changed to %s",
                    MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS));
            intervalDuration = MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS;
        }
        setPeriodic(intervalDuration, intervalDuration);
    }
```

But there are other ways to deal with that.

1. Write unit tests using **work-testing** library and ensure that your business logic works as expected.
2. Use dependency injection approach and provide a `OneTimeWorkRequest` in debug mode, for example:

```
interface Scheduler {
    fun schedule()
}

class DebugScheduler {
    fun schedule() {
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(
            OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker::class.java)
                .build()
        )
    }
}

class ProductionScheduler {
    fun schedule() {
        // your actual scheduling logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes, you can use the work-testing library as shown here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing

Specifically, you want to look at how to test periodic work: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/testing#periodic-work